# how to configure make file to find header files in other directories?

Tags: android-ndk, makefile

I keep getting this error from my Android.mk file:

```
/home/sansari/mytree2/tbt/app/app.c:23:19: fatal error: debug.h: No such file or directory
 #include <debug.h>
```

What I am trying to do is to import the source from another directory into my jni project. So I do not even have any statement for building app.c; it is being done by make implicit rules. Whist is great. My problem seems to be not knowing how to tell make hey look in the ../include directory for debug.h. That would be /home/sansari/mytree2/tbt/include. How do I do this please? What other information do you need to help me?

In order to provide a point of reference to you I need to add I am trying to run make from:

```
/home/sansari/AndroidStudioProjects/ThirdNDK/app/src/main/jni
```

I did issue the -p option to make; actually I am running ndk-build command which is a shell that runs make. And it seems like make is processing .mk fiels in my sources directories. Is it possible for make to do this implicitly without me adding an include for other make files? Here is what I have done to create my source files; it looks like make automatically finds .mk files in these directories and runs them:

```
FILE_LIST := $(wildcard /home/sansari/mytree2/tbt/*.c)
FILE_LIST += $(wildcard /home/sansari/mytree2/tbt/**/*.c)
FILE_LIST += $(wildcard /home/sansari/mytree2/tbt/**/**/*.c)
FILE_LIST += $(wildcard /home/sansari/mytree2/tbt/**/**/**/*.c)
FILE_LIST += $(wildcard /home/sansari/mytree2/tbt/**/**/**/**/*.c)
FILE_LIST += $(wildcard /home/sansari/mytree2/tbt/**/**/**/**/**/*.c)
LOCAL_MODULE    := HelloJNI
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(FILE_LIST:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%) HelloJNI.c
```

Just an update on this issue; I found out that it is possible for the VPATH statement work ok, and actually find the file. But then the compiler may not see it. I am still reading and digging, but if anyone can help I would certainly appreciate it.

@ognian - Hey thanks. I tried your suggestion and it does not seem to resolve my issue. I printed the content of LOCAL_C_FLAGS just to validate. Here is what I have:

```
/home/sansari/AndroidStudioProjects/ThirdNDK/app/src/main/jni/Android.mk:15: value of LOCAL_CFLAGS  -I/home/sansari/mytree2/lib/include/debug.h
/home/sansari/AndroidStudioProjects/ThirdNDK/app/src/main/jni/Android.mk:15: value of LOCAL_CFLAGS  -I/home/sansari/mytree2/lib/include/debug.h
/home/sansari/AndroidStudioProjects/ThirdNDK/app/src/main/jni/Android.mk:15: value of LOCAL_CFLAGS  -I/home/sansari/mytree2/lib/include/debug.h
/home/sansari/AndroidStudioProjects/ThirdNDK/app/src/main/jni/Android.mk:15: value of LOCAL_CFLAGS  -I/home/sansari/mytree2/lib/include/debug.h
/home/sansari/AndroidStudioProjects/ThirdNDK/app/src/main/jni/Android.mk:15: value of LOCAL_CFLAGS  -I/home/sansari/mytree2/lib/include/debug.h
/home/sansari/AndroidStudioProjects/ThirdNDK/app/src/main/jni/Android.mk:15: value of LOCAL_CFLAGS  -I/home/sansari/mytree2/lib/include/debug.h
/home/sansari/AndroidStudioProjects/ThirdNDK/app/src/main/jni/Android.mk:15: value of LOCAL_CFLAGS  -I/home/sansari/mytree2/lib/include/debug.h
[arm64-v8a] Compile        : HelloJNI <= app.c
/home/sansari/mytree2/tbt/app/app.c:23:19: fatal error: debug.h: No such file or directory
 #include <debug.h>
                   ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [/home/sansari/AndroidStudioProjects/ThirdNDK/app/src/main/obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/HelloJNI//home/sansari/mytree2/tbt/app/app.o] Erro
r 1
```

From what I read online, it seems to me I can point to the right directory but I do not know what else needs to happen for make to see it. There was also some comments online about the possibility of the compiler not seeing the required file. I think I need to learn more about what happens after I load variables with the right path. I looked into vpath and VPATH, but according to make manual the directory portion of the path is removed by make. So I tried creating a variable and loading the path of all of my header files into it. I then copied the content into GPATH variable, which according to the manual, would not get rid of the directory paths. But I guess I don't know what else I need to do. Here is my Androdi.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
#.INCLUDE_DIRS=make arch
#TLK_DIR = ../../../../../..$(LOCAL_PATH)/mytree2/tbt
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
#-I.$(LOCAL_PATH)../../../../../../mytree2/tbt/include/ \
SOURCES = /home/sansari/mytree2/tbt/%.c
#$(warning value of SOURCES is $(SOURCES))

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES = /home/sansari/mytree2/lib/include

vpath %.h $(INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES) 
CFLAGS += $(addprefix -I ,$(INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)) 
#$(warning value of CFLAGS is $(CFLAGS))
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -I/home/sansari/mytree2/lib/include/debug.h
$(warning value of LOCAL_CFLAGS $(LOCAL_CFLAGS))
#override CFLAGS += $(patsubst %,-I%,$(subst :, ,$(VPATH)))
HEATHER_LIST := $(wildcard /home/sansari/mytree2/tbt/*.h)
FILE_LIST := $(wildcard /home/sansari/mytree2/tbt/*.c)
#$(warning value of HEATHER_LIST is $(HEATHER_LIST))
#$(warning value of FILE_LIST is $(FILE_LIST))
FILE_LIST += $(wildcard /home/sansari/mytree2/tbt/**/*.c)
HEATHER_LIST += $(wildcard /home/sansari/mytree2/tbt/**/*.h)
#$(warning value of FILE_LIST is $(FILE_LIST))
#$(warning value of HEATHER_LIST is $(HEATHER_LIST))
#FILE_LIST += $(wildcard /home/sansari/mytree2/tbt/**/*.h)
FILE_LIST += $(wildcard /home/sansari/mytree2/tbt/**/**/*.c)
HEATHER_LIST += $(wildcard /home/sansari/mytree2/tbt/**/**/*.h)
#$(warning value of HEATHER_LIST is $(HEATHER_LIST))
#$(warning value of FILE_LIST is $(FILE_LIST))
#FILE_LIST += $(wildcard /home/sansari/mytree2/tbt/**/**/*.h)
FILE_LIST += $(wildcard /home/sansari/mytree2/tbt/**/**/**/*.c)
HEATHER_LIST += $(wildcard /home/sansari/mytree2/tbt/**/**/**/*.h)
#$(warning value of FILE_LIST is $(FILE_LIST))
#$(warning value of HEATHER_LIST is $(HEATHER_LIST))
#FILE_LIST += $(wildcard /home/sansari/mytree2/tbt/**/**/**/*.h)
FILE_LIST += $(wildcard /home/sansari/mytree2/tbt/**/**/**/**/*.c)
HEATHER_LIST += $(wildcard /home/sansari/mytree2/tbt/**/**/**/**/*.h)
#$(warning value of HEATHER_LIST is $(HEATHER_LIST))
#$( warning value of FILE_LIST is $(FILE_LIST))
#FILE_LIST += $(wildcard /home/sansari/mytree2/tbt/**/**/**/**/*.h)
FILE_LIST += $(wildcard /home/sansari/mytree2/tbt/**/**/**/**/**/*.c)
HEATHER_LIST += $(wildcard /home/sansari/mytree2/tbt/**/**/**/**/**/*.h)
#$( warning value of FILE_LIST is $(FILE_LIST))
#$(warning value of HEATHER_LIST is $(HEATHER_LIST))
GPATH = $(HEATHER_LIST)
#$(warning ******The Value of GPATH is $(GPATH))
#FILE_LIST += $(wildcard /home/sansari/mytree2/tbt/**/**/**/**/**/*.h)
LOCAL_MODULE    := HelloJNI
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/HEATHER_LIST
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(FILE_LIST:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%) HelloJNI.c
# Build all java files in the java subdirectory
#LOCAL_MODULE    := HelloJNI
#LOCAL_SRC_FILES := HelloJNI.c
# Tell it to build an APK
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
#include $(TLK_DIR)/makefile
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the header lookup option:

LOCAL_CFLAGS += -I{your-header-path-here}